# primitive types can't convert to Wrapper for an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, wrapper

I've been trying to learn how to use ArrayLists, however when I try to add primitive type values they don't convert to wrapper types in this machine.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegerListTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> integerListB = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int n = 1;
    if (n > 0 && n < 100) {
      while ((n > 0) && (n < 100)) {
        System.out.println("Inserire numero");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        if (n > 0 && n < 100) {
          integerList.add(valueOf(n));
          if (integerListB.contains(n) == false)
            integerListB.add(n);
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(integerList);
    System.out.println(integerListB);
  }
}
```

For example in this code the int inputs can't convert to Integers. I tried on another computer and it works just fine and I don't know why.

edit.1:
Thanks for all the replies, I really appreciate it.
Many of you noted that the method

> valueOf

in line 14 is incorrect and you're right. That was a correction I tried to solve the problem of this question.
I then tried to run the code you guys suggested and it still gives me the same error:

"error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Integer
integers.add( input );
^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -
Xdiags:verbose to get full output"

I believe my java auto-boxing isn't working but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Explain "they don't convert". What exactly is going wrong? What error message do you receive?

Comment: what/which method is `valueOf()` ? The code as posted should not even compile - (maybe it should be `Integer.valueOf()`, but it is missing the `Integer.` or corresponding `import static java.lang.Integer.*;`- actually `valueOf()` is not really needed since Java do auto-boxing in that case)

Comment: A couple things: 

1) as others already have noted: your code does not compile, because you did not specify valueOf. Either import it statically or just reference it explicitly (Integer.valueOf(n)))

2) besides that, your code compiles and runs

3) your if in line 9 is always true, because you defined n to be 1 one line above. You can ommit that line

4) it's not necessary to compare a boolean value by true/false like in line 15. It's fine just to check for if(integerListB.contains(n))


Keep learning and have fun while doing it!

Comment: @grange you meant `if ( ! integerListB.contains(n) )` - need negation to replace `== false` (or: "only add to the list if not already in the list")

Comment: @user85421: sure - it was just exemplary ;)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

You are working too hard. Simply add the primitive value to the object collection. Java automatically wraps (*boxes*).

```
 integers.add( input )
```

## Details

I am guessing your problem starts with `valueOf(n)`. You don't specify an object on which to call that method.

By the way, we can simplify the logic of your loop by using `break`.

The technical term you are looking for is [*boxing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science)), wrapping a primitive value within an object.

Simply passing a primitive to the `ArrayList#add` method is enough to invoke auto-boxing. The compiler and/or runtime sees a `int` primitive value being added to a `List` of `Integer` objects, and automatically wraps that primitive in a necessary `Integer` object.

By the way, in Java 21+, [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) is the more general super-interface of `List` & `ArrayList`. See [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
SequencedCollection < Integer > integers = new ArrayList <>( );
int input = -1;
do
{
    System.out.println( "Specify integer from 1 to 99 inclusive: " );
    input = scanner.nextInt( );
    if ( input > 0 && input < 100 )
    {
        integers.add( input );  // Auto-boxing in play. The primitive `int` value in our var `input` is boxed into an `Integer` object.
    } else
    {
        break;
    }
}
while ( true );
System.out.println( "integers = " + integers );
```

```
Specify integer from 1 to 99 inclusive: 
7
Specify integer from 1 to 99 inclusive: 
42
Specify integer from 1 to 99 inclusive: 
-666
integers = [7, 42]
```

Comment: I tried to run this code but it still gives me the same error:

"error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Integer
      integers.add( input );  
                    ^
 Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with - 
 Xdiags:verbose to get full output".

Answer (score 1):

Your class compiles and runs just fine. For the error message "int cannot be converted to Integer" to appear, it must be picking up another class called "Integer". Make sure you don't have a class called "Integer" in the same directory, or anywhere in your CLASSPATH.

The built-in primitive wrappers, such as `Integer`, `Character`, etc., are defined in the `java.lang` package. This package is automatically imported by the Java compiler. So, when you refer to a class named `Integer`, it automatically picks up `java.lang.Integer` - unless, that is, you also have a class named `Integer` defined in the same place as the class you're currently compiling. Then your own definition of `Integer` takes precedence.

The moral is to avoid giving your classes the same name as an existing Java class.

Comment: Oh that's it, now it runs just fine. It seems that i only deleted the Integer.java file but not the Integer.class bytecode file. Thank you very much for helping me!